# Running neo4j on same server with different port

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-shell

I am running two neo4j instance on one server but with different port. I changed port in neo4j.conf file, I am able to run it properly.
Now, when I execute the cypher query to create a node in the second instance from neo4j-shell, it is creating nodes in first instance.

I have not configured any database path. Assuming it will consider neo4j default database path i.e. data\databases\graph.db.

Please help me with my mistake.

Comment: When connecting with Neo4j-shell, do you specify the port with `-port`?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few option of neo4j-shell and It has -port. You can change it with used port or you review property such as path, file, config.
You should text ./neo4j-shell -help to see them.